# Query to find out details about who truncated tables in azure synapse

Tags: azure-synapse

We have configured our synapse to send data to log analytics workspace .. one table got truncated from my synapse so i want to find out who has done that operation .. i tried with "synapsesqlpoolexecrequests" but not getting results .

So can anybody help me with query to write in log analytics for above requirement ..

Comment: Can [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-overview#auditing-of-microsoft-support-operations) help you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a cross-post from Microsoft Q&A: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/385289/how-to-check-logs-in-synapse.html

All details about who ran a query are available in the monitoring tab in the Synapse workspace:

[image]