# how to check delete activity on table in Azure synapse

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I want to check the log where i want to see who have delete or truncated the table in Azure Synapse.
Can any one please help me?

Please note I am also trying to check in Dedicated SQL pool.

Regards,

Comment: can you add what you have tried?? and error you are facing

Comment: @PratikLad I haven't tried anything yet.  May be something can be tried in ADF. But am not sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67793179 CHECK THIS IF IT HELPS?

Comment: @PratikLad in Dedicated sql pool?

Comment: YES FOR BOTH SERVERLESS AND DEDICATED

Answer (score 0):

To get to know the who executed the Drop and truncate on table there are two options are available.

1. Within the Synapse workspace, comprehensive information regarding the execution of queries is accessible through the monitoring tab. This section provides detailed insights into query execution, including essential data like the user who initiated the query.
   [image]
2. You need to enable auditing on the workspace and the database withy log analytics workspace.[Enable Auditing in Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-overview)
   [image]
   Then go to your Log analytics workspace. and use below query to get the query execution details on synapse databases.

Use below query:

```
SQLSecurityAuditEvents
| where Statement contains "DROP" or Statement contains "TRUNCATE"
| project Statement,DatabaseName,SessionServerPrincipalName,LogicalServerName
```

[image]